# arrayListOf(), sortedWith, compareBy Java equivalent

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm converting a Kotlin based Android app into a Java based one. But got a problem with several Kotlin's methods, especially with the `arrayListOf(), sortedWith(), compareBy()` methods. The converting tools from Android Studio gave even more confusing result.

The method in Kotlin:

```
fun getSupportedVideoSize(mediaCodec: MediaCodec, mime: String, preferredResolution: Size): Size {
    
    if (mediaCodec.codecInfo.getCapabilitiesForType(mime)
            .videoCapabilities.isSizeSupported(preferredResolution.width, preferredResolution.height))
        return preferredResolution

    val resolutions = arrayListOf(
        Size(176, 144),
        Size(320, 240),
        Size(320, 180),
        Size(640, 360),
        Size(720, 480),
        Size(1280, 720),
        Size(1920, 1080)
    )

    val pix = preferredResolution.width * preferredResolution.height
    val preferredAspect = preferredResolution.width.toFloat() / preferredResolution.height.toFloat()

    val nearestToFurthest = resolutions.sortedWith(compareBy(
        {
            pix - it.width * it.height
        },
        {
            val aspect = if (it.width < it.height) it.width.toFloat() / it.height.toFloat()
            else it.height.toFloat()/it.width.toFloat()
            (preferredAspect - aspect).absoluteValue
        }))

    for (size in nearestToFurthest) {
        if (mediaCodec.codecInfo.getCapabilitiesForType(mime).videoCapabilities.isSizeSupported(size.width, size.height))
            return size
    }

    throw RuntimeException("Couldn't find supported resolution")
}
```

Converted method in Java:

```
public static Size getSupportedVideoSize(MediaCodec mediaCodec, String mime, Size preferredResolution) {
    if (mediaCodec.getCodecInfo().getCapabilitiesForType(mime).getVideoCapabilities().isSizeSupported(preferredResolution.getWidth(), preferredResolution.getHeight())) {
        return preferredResolution;
    } else {
        ArrayList<Size> resolutions = new ArrayList<>();
        final int pix = preferredResolution.getWidth() * preferredResolution.getHeight();
        final float preferredAspect = (float)preferredResolution.getWidth() / (float)preferredResolution.getHeight();
    }
    
    for (nearestToFurthest: Size size) {
        if (mediaCodec.getCodecInfo().getCapabilitiesForType(mime).getVideoCapabilities().isSizeSupported(size.width, size.height)) {
            return size;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: I don't know how to convert the above 3 Kotlin's methods into Java equivalents.

Comment: Just out of curiosity...why?

Comment: Because I'm not used to yet to Kotlin (despite its simplicity over Java) and still want to focus on finishing my app (for now) that is currently written in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know Kotlin but I assume these would be equivalent:

`arrayListOf` --> `List.of`

(this is unmodiafiable list, if you really want arraylist, use `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(...))` )

`sortedWith(compareBy(...))` --> `sort([Comparator or lambda expression])`